# Why does gtk-gnash eat CPU resources at 90%+?

Tags: linux, iceweasel

I use Iceweasel with Debian Squeeze. When I browse some websites, e.g. http://www.dedoimedo.com, it sometimes happens that the gtk-gnash program uses more than 90% of my CPU resources. When I close that website, the gtk-gnash sleeps. If I open the website again and browse it there will be no activity by gtk-gnash for a while.

The gtk-gnash activity at that level looks odd.

1. What is gtk-gnash responsible for?
2. Is the high level activity of gtk-gnash safe (e.g. for the CPU)?
3. Is there a more methodical solution (besides the one mentioned above) for making gtk-gnash calm?

Comment: 1) According to http://wiki.gnashdev.org/GTK the gtk+ programs are toolkits for creating graphical user interfaces. According to http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/python-gtk-gnash the gtk-gnash program may be used as a plugin for several popular browsers. It supports playing media from a disk or streaming over a network connection.

Comment: 2) According to http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/ubuntu-10-10-crash-the-unholy-gtk-gnash/ the high-level activity of gtk-gnash could have undesirable consequences. The same link suggests a solution for addressing the problem.

Comment: 3) According to http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/ubuntu-10-10-crash-the-unholy-gtk-gnash/ removing the gtk-gnash might solve the problem. Could there be a better solution? Let's search for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Gnash is just a free Adobe Flash replacement, responsible for playing videos and animations inside websites. As it is under heavy development (I think) if it's having problems on your system, you can always install the official plugin (Debian package: flashplugin-nonfree).

More information: http://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer/